# How to optimize the algorithm for counting lines of code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I create an application that counts the number of lines of code in the Github repository. The user enters a link to the repository, after which a table appears that consists of the columns: "File name", "Total", "Code", "Comments", "Empty."

My algorithm works, but when a large file starts processing my page freezes. Can you please tell me how to optimize this algorithm?

```
fetch(....).then(result => {
                if (itmes.type==='file'){
                const content = Buffer.from(result.data.content, 'base64').toString();
                CountCode(content);
                }


                  //content is string
 function CountCode(content) {

        console.log('processing');

        //Count total
        let lines = content.split(/\r|\r\n|\n/);
        let total_lines = lines.length;

        //Count comments like /* */
        let comment = content.replace(/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/g,"");
        let comment2 = comment.split(/\r|\r\n|\n/);
        let comment_lines = total_lines - comment2.length;
        console.log(comment_lines);

        //Count comments like //
        let comment3 = content.replace(/^[/][/].*/gm,"");
        let comment4 = comment3.split(/\r|\r\n|\n/);
        let comment_lines2 = total_lines - comment4.length;
        console.log(comment_lines2);

        //Count Total lines
        let total_comment_lines=comment_lines+comment_lines2;
        console.log(total_comment_lines);
        //Count empty lines//
        let empty = content.replace(/^\s*$/gm,"");
        let empty2 = empty.split(/\r|\r\n|\n/);
        let total_empty= total_lines - empty2.length;
        console.log(total_empty);
        //Count Total Code
        let total_code = total_lines - total_empty - total_comment_lines;
        console.log(total_code);

        console.log('TOTAL: '+total_lines+'  COMMENT: '+total_comment_lines+ ' EMPTY: '+ total_empty+ ' CODE: '+ total_code);
    }
```

Comment: It would be faster to use regular expressions to count lines and commented lines than using split everywhere, which creates new string objects

Comment: i think the problem is more related to the fact that the entire file is buffered into memory, this will create a performance hit. I suggest to modify your code to ajax fetch file content in blocks.